# Short story about a family in a spaceship who land on a planet and encounter a giant baby

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story a year or so ago. It was a part of an anthology of short stories from various authors. I cannot put a lower bound on the year the story would have been published, but it definitely would have been published before the 1990s. It had a nice golden age sci-fi feel to the descriptions. It wasn't very long, maybe 10-15 pages in total.

In the story there is a typical family - mother, father, one daughter, and two sons (I'm unsure how many children exactly, there were at least two). I think one of the sons is the youngest child, maybe 4-5 years old. The other siblings would have been younger than 10, if their ages were even given. They are in a spaceship; either they are heading to somewhere in particular, or they are running away from Earth for some reason. The father seemed to be very focused on getting to their destination. Maybe they were going on holiday and left Earth behind for a bit.

After some preamble (they have been travelling for some time; a few hours or perhaps a few days) they land on a planet and, once the surface is deemed safe by the father, they explore a bit. They don't manage to get far though, because a giant baby appears and starts to use the spaceship as a toy! I think the baby is humanoid, just like a normal baby but the size of a skyscraper. It starts out curious, but quickly becomes dangerous, as one could imagine.

I think the youngest child is quite excited to play with the giant baby, but is sternly told off by his father. They manage to just barely escape the baby's clutches and continue their journey.